# Wrong Values of Time on D3 plot on Xaxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am plotting a graph on D3, I am getting time on Xaxis as shown in Figure.
[image: Figure of Graph]
My time input is **19:58:00**
I am getting conlose output of time as **Mon Jan 01 1900 19:57:00 GMT-0800 (PST)**

**Code to parse time is**
parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S")

**CODE TO PLOT Xaxis**

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(parseDate.parse(d.Time))
        d.Time = parseDate.parse(d.Time);
        d.X = +d.X;
    });
});
```

Sample Data 
Time         X
17:03:00    11
17:04:00    79
17:05:00    45
17:06:00    55
17:07:00    55
17:08:00    11
17:09:00    21

Comment: Can you please post the d3 code that draws the x-axis and a sample of your data?

Comment: @tusharck this is not the code that creates the axis. Please post your axis generator. It starts with `d3.svg.axis()`.

Comment: do you use `d3.scale.Linear`?